# How does IntelliJ changes files before commit if they are already added to git

Tags: git, intellij-idea

IntelliJ has a number of options that affect a file's content, like, for example, optimize imports, performed before commit. I'm wondering how IntelliJ achieves this when using GIT? Git adds files to its storage not on commit but on add - `git add filename`, so I don't see how the studio can change this file's content before commit. Can someone please clarify?

Comment: It probably does `git add filename` (possibly again if it was done already) after it has made it's changes, but before the commit.

Comment: @JonasCz, have you tried this yourself? The reason I'm asking is that I've tried to use `before commit` features on `webstorm` and [it didn't work at all](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29861181/how-to-use-reformat-code-before-commit-feature). I haven't yet tested that for IntelliJ. But I'm curious in general how studio handles that so I thought I'd ask similiar questions with IntelliJ users :)

Comment: No, I haven't tried it, just an assumption / thought. Do post an answer here when you find out !

Comment: @JonasCz, sure, let's see if anyone answers) Maybe you could upvote this question to make it more appealing to the public)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA and any other IDE only can make pre-commit changes if a commit is done with IDE tools. In that case it's something like that:

1. Save the list of indexed files.
2. Process those files (e.g. reformat code)
3. `git add filename` for each file of the list. That's done by IDE in a hidden console that can be opened with Cmd+9 (Mac) or, I suppose, Ctrl+9 on any other OS.

If you commit with any other tool, IDE cannot intercept that commit and apply changes.

In this example I changed two files, added them manually, then commited with IntelliJ IDEA tool, picking "reformat code". One can see how it re-adds files in a fancy manner.

[image: IntelliJ IDEA re-adds processed files before commit]